# Monit check processes for multiple pidfiles

Tags: node.js, monit, pm2

I have a Nodejs Web app with multiple node process, which I start using `pm2 start app.js` multiple times.

To monitor these processes usinf monit, I created a init script using pm2's : `pm2 startup ubuntu` command. Then, in the monit config file for my App, I use this init script as start and stop program commands for monit. Then I use something like `check process pm2_1 with pidfile /path/to/node-pidfile`, for both the processes in the monit config file.

I would like monit to check the pidfiles of both these processes and when either or both processes are down, restart both the processes. So, here's what my my-webapp.monitrc looks like :

```
    check process pm2_1
        with pidfile /root/.pm2/pids/proc1-0.pid
        start program = "/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh start"
        stop program = "/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh stop"

    check process pm2_2 
       with pidfile /root/.pm2/pids/proc2-1.pid
       start program = "/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh start"
       stop program = "/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh stop"
```

The problem is, if either of the processes is down,it works. But if both processes are down, monit executes the start command twice.

Is there a way to have a "OR" condition for check process to monitor multiple different pidfiles and execute the same start and stop commands only once ?

Comment: What about restarting instead of starting the process?

Comment: Just use an ecosystem file to manage multiple applications. It is much simpler.